# MS-Access How to use iif in query criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a search form containing a text box and I want to filter a field based on value greater than value entered in text box but return all the field when the text box is empty.
I wrote below code in query criteria for this purpose but got error

```
IIf(IsNull(TextBox); TheField; >TextBox))
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specified as the criteria for a particular field within the query builder in MS Access, the expression you have entered will likely be interpreted as the following `where` clause:

```
where TheField = IIf(IsNull(TextBox), TheField, TheField > TextBox))
```

Which will likely yield a data type mismatch error if `TheField` does not hold a boolean value, since the *else* branch will yield a `where` clause of:

```
where TheField = (TheField > TextBox)
```

Which will be either of the following:

```
where TheField = True
where TheField = False
```

---

Instead, I would suggest specifying the following as your SQL `where` clause:

```
where Forms!YourFormName!YourTextBox is null or TheField > Forms!YourFormName!YourTextBox
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
where (textbox is null or thefield > textbox)
```